# How to overcome "An array is allocated or declared with size zero" restriction?

Tags: c

I have next structure

```
typedef struct _COMMAND_MESSAGE {
    R_COMMAND Command;
    size_t DataLength;
    UCHAR Data[];
} COMMAND_MESSAGE, *PCOMMAND_MESSAGE;
```

I am using Data as buffer to pass data between kernel and user mode. Now i want to read a wide string from buffer.

```
// wchar_t MyMessage2[100]; - Works
wchar_t MyMessage2[cmd->DataLength]; //C2466: An array is allocated or declared with size zero.
int byte_offset = 0;   

// read message from the data stream
wcscpy(MyMessage2, (wchar_t*)&cmd->Data[byte_offset]);
```

How to initialize wchar array of known length from cmd->DataLength? I don't know at compile time max string size. It can be HUGE sometime.

Comment: Did you initialized `DataLength` (or read its value)?

Comment: @haccks  Yes - it is real length of string in Data

Comment: Then how `dataLength` becomes `0`?

Comment: @haccks it isn't 0.. the compiler just tell so at compile time

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @haccks VS 2013 WDK8.1 toolset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message it appears that you are using a Microsoft compiler. Variable-length arrays were added in the C99 language standard, with which Microsoft does not fully support. To work around this issue you would need to allocate `MyMessage2` in the dynamic store (the heap), like this:

```
wchar_t MyMessage2* = malloc(cmd->DataLength * sizeof(*MyMessage2));
... // Use the buffer here
free(MyMessage2);
```

> I don't know at compile time max string size. It can be HUGE sometime.

Then you should use the dynamic store approach even with a standard-compliant compiler. You should never allocate a variable-length array in the automatic store (the stack) when there is a possibility of it being huge sometimes, because an attempt to allocate a large array on the stack can lead to stack overflow and a crash at runtime. Typically, the dynamic store lets you allocate more memory than the automatic one.